# В csv записывается список из int, а читается как str

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

До записи в csv могу обратиться к любому элементу массива и считать правильно. Но после чтения из этого же файла, списки превращаются в строки и тогда уже не могу прочитать как числа.

Вот код:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [['a', [11,22]],['b',[33,44]]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df = df.transpose()
print(df)
print(df[1][1])
print(type(df[1][1]))
b = df[1][1]
print(b[1])
print(type(b[1]))
df.to_csv('i.csv', sep = ',', header = None, encoding='1251', index = False)
dff = pd.read_csv('ii.csv',sep = ',', header = None, encoding='1251')
print(dff)
print(type(dff))
ind = dff[1][1]
print(ind)
print(type(ind))
ii = ind[0]
print(ii)
print(type(ii))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

после транспонирования (`df = df.transpose()`) вы получили DataFrame со списками в ячейках - это автоматически преобразует тип столбца в `object`, т.к. список является сложным/составным объектом (не скаляром):

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
          0         1
0         a         b
1  [11, 22]  [33, 44]

In [3]: df.dtypes
Out[3]:
0    object
1    object
dtype: object
```

Обратите внимание на содержимое CSV файла:

```
a,b
"[11, 22]","[33, 44]"
```

любой CSV парсер будет воспринимать это как строки, а не как списки целых:

```
In [7]: d2 = pd.read_csv(r'D:\temp\i.csv')

In [8]: d2
Out[8]:
          a         b
0  [11, 22]  [33, 44]

In [9]: d2.iat[0,0]
Out[9]: '[11, 22]'

In [10]: type(d2.iat[0,0])
Out[10]: str
```

Большинство методов Pandas не будет работать со сложными (не скалярными) типами столбцов и разработчики Pandas рекомендуют использовать только скаляры в ячейках DataFrame / Series, чтобы избежать многих ненужных проблем:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
          0         1
0         a         b
1  [11, 22]  [33, 44]

In [12]: df.sum()
Out[12]: Series([], dtype: float64)

In [13]: df.sum(axis=1)
Out[13]:
0                  ab
1    [11, 22, 33, 44]
dtype: object

In [14]: df.max()
Out[14]: Series([], dtype: float64)

In [15]: df.max(axis=1)
Out[15]:
0           b
1    [33, 44]
dtype: object
```

**Вывод:** храните данные в таком виде, чтобы в ячейках были скаляры одного типа данных (`int`, `float`, `datetime`, `str`).

PS в дополнение к указанному выше - формат CSV не сохраняет информацию о типах данных. Например при записи/чтении столбцов типа `datetime` придется прилагать дополнительные усилия, чтобы преобразовать такие столбцы к `datetime` типу. Кроме того парсинг CSV - [очень медленный процес по сравнению с другими цифровыми форматами](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010212/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-upload-a-big-csv-file-in-notebook-to-work-with-python/37012035#37012035).

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. М.б. оно для данного случая, но работает. После считывания файла удаляю "строчные" символы и получаю нормальный тип .
Вот весь код:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
df = [['x', [1, 2]], ['y', [3, 4]]]
dff = pd.DataFrame(df)
dff.to_csv('i.csv', sep = ',', header = None, encoding='1251', index = False)
dff = pd.read_csv('i.csv',sep = ',', header = None, encoding='1251')
print(dff)
print(type(dff))
print('##########')
ind = list(dff[1][0])
ind.remove('[')
ind.remove(']')
ind.remove(',')
ind.remove(' ')
print(ind)
print(type(ind))
print('###########')
ii = ind
print(ii[1])
print(type(ii)) 
print('###########')
```